# MySql query to return only valid combinations of values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone help me write a mysql query that will look at a table in the m_sku column and see if m_sku has multiple records for a single value: for instance ABC has 3 records (Figure A). And if m_sku has multiple instance of a record check to see if the combination of m_sku & sku is different on any of them, then return that value. For instance, all these three records have different m_sku/sku combinations as seen in figure B.

Here is my main table... 
Figure A.

```
 id | sku        | m_sku        
 ---------------------------------------------
 1  | 123        | ABC
 2  | 123        | ABC
 3  | 345        | ABC
 4  | 456        | DEF
 5  | 567        | EFG
 6  | 678        | HIJ
 7  | 567        | HIJ
 8  | 890        | KLM
```

Here is what we are looking for... 
Figure B.

```
 1  | 123        | ABC
 2  | 123        | ABC
 3  | 345        | ABC
 6  | 678        | HIJ
 7  | 567        | HIJ
```

Here is only what I want to return...

```
 id | m_sku        
 ---------------------------------------------
 1  | ABC
 2  | HIJ
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m_sku FROM table GROUP BY m_sku HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sku) > 1;
```

This will make sure that two or more rows with the same sku/m_sku pairs won't be returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not test but try this :

```
select distinct m_sku from your_table group by m_sku having count(sku) > 1
```

Comment: This would also return multiple rows without a different sku/m_sku combinations...for instance the first two rows in the table if the third was missing.

Comment: don't understand. It's return ABC and HIJ in the example. There is not a "count distinct", only a count.

Comment: Yes, but only because it's a valid result with his 8 row example. He specifically asked for "if the combination of m_sku & sku is different on any of them, then return that value"

Comment: NewInTheBusiness, you are correct, your example works much better.

Comment: Ok... just add the distinct. :)